# EmailNotConfirmedException not rendering the anchor '<a>' tag on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, exception-error

I am using **Magento2.3.5p1** and working to modify the message of email confirmation on **checkout page** by adding the link to resend confirmation link.

I have overridden the **AccountManagement.php** model from Magento_Customer and changed code as below :

```
$value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) 
{
  throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__('This account is not confirmed.'.
 '<a target="_blank" href='.$value.'> Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.'));
}
```

**The result is an error message on the frontend that has the literal text**

`"This account is not confirmed. <a href="http://localhost:8080/ch/customer/example/url">Click here</a>  to resend confirmation email.`"

Which is obviously is NOT a clickable link.
I want it to be a clickable link with message.

Anyone please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
 throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(
    __(
        'This account is not confirmed. <a target="_blank" href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', 
         $value
      )
   );
```

still, maybe it would be a good idea to move this message to session messages.

---

***LE:*** the exception messages are not rendered as HTML, suggestion to set the message in session should be a better option.

Comment: Didn't worked for me.

Comment: So what I think it's that the exception messages are not rendered as HTML. Can you move the above message to session?

Comment: Yes, It might be possible that the exception messages are not rendered as HTML. Thankyou :)

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer above to mention my suggestion to a more visible place.